# Using TouchID on simulator

Tags: ios, ionic2, emulation, touch-id

I'm trying to use TouchID within my Ionic 2 app. I have an iphone 5c, so I can't test it on real device.

I imported the package :

```
import { TouchID } from 'ionic-native';
```

Then, I tested the first function (I already activated touchID in the hardware section of the emulator):

```
TouchID.isAvailable()
.then(
  res => console.log('TouchID is available!'),
  err => console.error('TouchID is not available', err)
);
```

Everything works fine. Now what I would like to do, is testing this function :

```
TouchID.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please')
.then(
  res => console.log('Ok', res),
  err => console.error('Error', err)
);
```

It's possible to test it on emulator ?
The emulator can listen to fingerprint action ?

Comment: Simulator is the right term here - the question will be found easier.

Answer (score 20):

Yes is possible!

With the simulator open you click in Hardware -> Touch ID Enrolled to make the Touch ID active

[Touch ID Enrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnZl3.png)

To test the Touch ID you go in Hardware -> Simulate Finger Touch -> Matching or Non-Matching

[Simulate Finger Touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytuSD.png)

Comment: I have the version: 10.0 (SimulatorApp-726.7)
When you click on : Hardware > Touch ID > Matching Touch, there's nothing happen

Comment: The Touch ID question is on the screen of the simulator? If yes, can you show me the code you are using to see if is matching?

Comment: I can't paste all the code here, I put it as an answer :)

Comment: Extending the answer. For new devices you will see Face ID in place of Touch ID.

Answer (score 16):

Anyone who is using latest Xcode (version 12x), there is no `Hardware` menu, it's been replace by 'Feature`. So to enroll the touch id,

1. Open simulator
2. Go to `Features -> Touch Id -> Enrolled`

[image]

Comment: Weird ... mine only has Face ID in the `Features` menu ...

Comment: Try using a touch id phone, like an iPhone 8

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of xCode:

1. **Enable** Touch ID by clicking in emulator top menu-> *Hardware -> Touch ID -> Enrolled*
2. Then **to emulate Touch** in emulator top menu -> *Hardware -> Touch ID -> Matching/Non-matching Touch*

Answer (score 0):

This is my code @josé-neto

```
ngOnInit() {
      if(window["plugins"]){
        window["plugins"].touchid.isAvailable(
          function() {
              console.log("isAvailable ok !");
              window["plugins"].touchid.verifyFingerprint(
                'Scan your fingerprint please',
                function(msg) {console.log('verifyFingerprint ok: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))}, 
                function(msg) {console.log('verifyFingerprint not ok: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))} 
              );
          }, 
          function(msg) {
            console.log('isAvailable not ok: ' + JSON.stringify(msg))
          }
        );
      }
      else{
        console.log('window["plugins"] not ok');
      }
  }
```

in the console, It displays "isAvailable ok !" then executes the function verifyFingerprint. (it display :verifyFingerprint not ok: null). It's not waiting the user action (fingerprint)